# Register interfaces with no concrete implementations to return a generated type/proxy

Tags: castle-windsor, structuremap

I want to auto register all interfaces which name ends with "Service" and also doesn't have concrete implementations to be resolved to a generated type/proxy (which off course differs per interface).

So when I want to resolve `IContractService` I want it to return a proxied object. I got this idea from this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/456125/Injection-of-WCF-proxies-in-ASP-NET-MVC-controller) where they implemented it in some way with Castle Windsor.

What would be the structuremap approach for achieving this. I tried all kind of things with custom conventions and all but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using Castle's Dynamic Proxy and a StructureMap convention. BTW. I also renamed some of the classes mentioned in the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/456125/Injection-of-WCF-proxies-in-ASP-NET-MVC-controller).

```
public class InfraRegistry : Registry
{
        public InfraRegistry()
        {                     
            For<IClientProviderFactory>().Use<WcfClientProviderProviderFactory>();

            Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.AssemblyContainingType<MidleWareServiceConvention>();                    
                    scan.Convention<MidleWareServiceConvention>();
                });   
        }
}

public class MidleWareServiceConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
        private readonly ProxyGenerator _proxyGen = new ProxyGenerator();

        public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
        {
            if (type.IsInterface && type.Name.EndsWith("Service", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                registry.For(type)
                        .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                        .Use(
                            context =>
                            _proxyGen.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(type,
                                                                        new WcfInterceptor(
                                                                            context.GetInstance<IClientProviderFactory>())));
            }
        }
}
```